# Building a cache table, database helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have a few tables of possible combinations for item names, like base name, prefixes and suffixes - however it isnt very good to search directly in these tables as I have to generate the combinations every time, to fix it I created a Cache table where I plan to run some cron job to fill it up. I have to create a script that populates the cache and it just doesnt seem smart to build the SQL procedurally with string concatenations.

Is there anyway I can insert a SQL result set into a table? Without creating the actualy INSERT statement manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any way to insert records with doing an insert, but you can insert a result set in a couple of different ways:

The first method is an INSERT INTO SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM Tabl2
```

The second is a SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
INTO Table2
FROM Table1
```

I don't know if that helps to answer your question, but hopefully it will put you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library, takes DataReader, DataTable or any List object as parameter... http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com